# Apache Passenger displaying my Rails application contents?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

I have installed mod_rails (phusion passenger) for Apache on Ubuntu 11.10. Ruby and Rails are running fine, and so does mod_rails.

I have setup a site on dev.localhost, which is my ruby app. The app is called my_project which resides in var/www/my_project

My virtualhost for it successfully points to the 'public' directory of my ruby app and it seems to work. If I access dev.localhost - my ruby application works perfectly, there are no complaints. However, if I access localhost/my_project, my entire ruby application is displayed, the Gemfile, the controllers, all it's directories - everything. It displays the directory's content.

My virtual hosts file for my rails app:

```
<VirtualLHost *:80>
RailsEnv development
ServerName dev.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is this? I can't figure it out. I've tried .htaccess files, everything, but those obviously also reflect on dev.localhost.

How can I stop people from seeing the ruby application files on say localhost/my_project? It doesn't display it on dev.localhost, it displays the site 100%.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You've attached a Name-based VirtualHost (by using `ServerName dev.localhost`) to port 80 on all interfaces, but you haven't set a default VirtualHost so it's using the main DocumentRoot configuration (probably in `/etc/apache2/conf/apache2.conf`).  Two options:

- Replace `*:80` with `_default_:80` and remove the `ServerName` option, meaning this VirtualHost will handle all connections on port 80 regardless of the `Host:` header provided.
- Add another `sites-enabled` file with a `_default_:80` VirtualHost that points to a `DocumentRoot` containing a page informing users there is no site configured on this hostname.  This approach is forward-looking if you plan to deploy multiple name-based VirtualHosts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a `+Indexes` set somewhere in your apache2 configuration. Adding this block to your VirtualHost block (or into your httpd.conf) should solve it.

```
<Directory "/var/www/my_project">
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

This will override a `+Indexes` option that is set somewhere in your httpd configuration to serve all /var/www content as indexable.

Also, instead of a catchall virtualhost, consider `<VirtualLHost dev.localhost:80>`.